# Google apps script – Поиск и копирование новых данных (googlesheets)

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Есть таблица 1 (Источник данных), куда каждый день загружаются новые операции (1 операция = 1 строка). Количество операций в день произвольное. В последнем столбце (Тип операции) вручную надо указать тип операции.

Есть таблица 2 (Прямые продажи), в которую должны автоматически подгружаться все новые операции из таблицы источника данных, у которых необходимый тип операции (в примере это тип "Прямые продажи").

Я по гайдам написал скрипт, который копирует данные из таблицы 1 в таблицу 2, но проблема в том, что при каждом запуске он копирует ВСЕ подходящие данные, уже со второго запуска создавая в таблице 2 дубликаты.

Понимаю, что нужно доработать скрипт, чтобы он при добавлении новых данных в таблицу 1:

1. находил в таблице 1 последнюю строку из таблицы 2 (недопустимость дубликатов)
2. пробегался по всем строкам под ней в таблице 1 (поиск новых подходящих операций)
3. забирал все строки с необходимым типом операции в таблицу 2 (копирование новых операций)

Но компетенций на такого рода модернизации не хватает (к сожалению далек от программирования), я застрял еще на этапе сравнения двух массивов данных. Пробовал искать похожие кейсы, но везде предлагается после изъятия нужных данных очищать страницу (что в моем случае недопустимо, данные в таблице 1 должны оставаться), соответственно и перебор строк там не рассматривается.

Буду признателен если кто-нибудь сможет помочь доработать скрипт или направит в какую сторону искать/покажет похожие примеры, чтобы было где подсмотреть.

(в примере я разместил обе таблицы в одном файле на разных листах, и количество столбцов сократил для визуального облегчения. Но важный момент что сравнивать нужно будет Всю строку, чтобы загружать только уникальные операции)

Ссылка на таблицу:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D5K33BMi5aLDcZkDYlKSXBpag2av_FrzNOQ4O24ueVw/edit#gid=1217659551

Код который получилось написать:

```
    function copyrows(){
    const ss_sourse = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Источник Данных");
    const ss_target = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Прямые продажи");
    const ss_sourse_lr = ss_sourse.getLastRow();
    const ss_target_lr = ss_target.getLastRow();

    let sortRange = ss_sourse.getSheetValues(3,1,ss_sourse_lr, 6);
    let b2b_direct = 1;

    for (var i = 1; i <= sortRange.length; i++){
      let name = ss_sourse.getRange(i,6).getValue();

      if (name == "Прямые продажи"){
        let rowValues = ss_sourse.getRange(i, 1, 1, 6).getValues();
        ss_target.getRange(ss_target_lr+b2b_direct, 1, 1, 6).setValues(rowValues);
        b2b_direct++;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо построить индекс листа-приемника, по которому вы будете определять уникальные значения.

Далее необходимо отфильтровать данные листа-источника на основе ваших параметров и присутствия данных в индексе листа-приемника.

И потом вставить значения.

```
function copyrows() {
  const to = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Прямые продажи');
  const toIndex = to.getDataRange().getValues()
    .map(calcIndex_);
  const fromValues = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Источник данных')
    .getDataRange().getValues()
    .slice(2)
    .filter(row => {
      return row[5] === 'Прямые продажи' && toIndex.indexOf(calcIndex_(row)) === -1
    });
  if (fromValues.length) {
    const lr = to.getLastRow();
    if (lr >= to.getMaxRows())
      to.insertRowAfter(lr);
    to.getRange(lr + 1, 1, fromValues.length, fromValues[0].length)
      .setValues(fromValues);
  }
}

const calcIndex_ = (row) => {
  const [a, b, c, d, e] = row;
  const b_ = b.getTime ? b.getTime() : 0;
  return [a, b_, c, d, e].join('_');
}
```

Пример в Таблице https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13hTtR4Z5LHHOtdJhswstjHBq6GIsEMGzj96nImce5DM/edit?usp=sharing